# next button conflict with autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, click, autoplay

On a slider projet, l've got a small problem.

When the user user click on next button, it stops my `autoplay` function and indeed, thats what l want. But my `autoplay` has for instruction the click of `next` button.

So which condition l have to put for :

if the user pressed the `next`, stop autoplay, else : continue autoplay.

Maybbe with `.trigger('click', param...)` in `autoplay` function ?

Here is a part of the script :

```
$(function() {
function autoplay() {
    timer = setInterval(function() {
        $('#next-icon').click();
    }, 5000);
};
$('#next-icon').click(function() {
    imgIndex++;
    if (imgIndex > totalImg.length - 1) imgIndex = 0; 
    var nextImgSrc = galry.children('.item:eq('+(imgIndex)+')').children('img').attr('src');
    slider.fadeOut(function() {
        slider.html('');
        var     newImgName = nextImgSrc.split('.'),
            newSrcB4 = newImgName[0]+'-b4.'+newImgName[1];
        $('<img src="'+newSrcB4+'" class="hover" alt="">').hide().appendTo('.slider');
        $('<img src="'+nextImgSrc+'" alt="">').appendTo('.slider');
        $('.slider-icon').children('.txt').text((imgIndex + 1)+' of '+totalImg.length);
        slider.fadeIn();
        $('#pause-icon').hide(); $('#play-icon').show();
        clearInterval(timer);
    });
}); });
```

Many thanks.